# Confused about a post not actually supported by anything in attic. hip valley roof

Tags: framing, roof

I was cleaning in my attic, and air sealing some electrical boxes, when I noticed something that looks like a supporting post that was nailed to the thin tongue and grove floor.  It's in a hip and valley roof.

Post (or stud? IDK what this thing is) has the romex running down it.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So here is the question, what is it?  It can't be providing structural support, it's nailed to the floor and not even directly on a joist, Is this something that should be structural?  Could it be a temporary support brace only used during the original construction?

Across from it, there is a row of actual studs. .

Comment: Better pictures would help to answer your question. The first 2 are useless, and the 3rd needs more light to see where the post goes.

Comment: A bit hard to tell still, but it kind of looks like there used to be more there. Those few studs along that same exterior surface, do they look like they were rough cut off? It does look structural, but I'm concerned that there was once more structural support that was later removed.

Comment: @blarg the pictures should be better now.

Comment: @blarg I do not see anything that leads me to think it was a modification of the original house construction.  The cieling is original, lath and plaster.  The most that could have happened was adding the tounge and groove boards on top of the ceiling joists, but that door is not new construction.

Comment: @blarg, look next to the cut studs, is it possible those boards somehow transfer load to the windowed wall's studs?

Comment: I wouldn't remove it, but as @blarg says, I would be very concerned about the studs that have been cut.  I would suggest that, at the very least, you ask for an opinion from a builder/carpenter.

Comment: @RohitGupta  I would be more concerned about the cut studs, if they were cut after the house was built, but there is no reason to believe that was the case.  They don't line up with anything underneath.  I'll ask a framer... thought that was who the question would attract.